# Mapper Task hung there because of merge operation in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

My hadoop job's mapper task always hung there even its progress is 100%, its status is still running. And I see lots of merge operation is done in the mapper task log. I have already change the parameter io.sort.mb and io.sort.factor to a larger number. But it didn't solve my issue. I have around 2000 mapper task and the overall output size of mapper task is 200G, that means each mapper task's output size is around 100M, that should not been a large size for me. So I don't understand why mapper task do so many of merge operation

Any ideas on this issue ? Thanks

And here's my log (BTW, what does the size number mean below ? ):

```
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44335 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45076 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44057 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45369 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45388 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45816 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44765 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45761 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45379 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44456 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45581 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45939 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45418 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 45241 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44809 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
[INFO] Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 44736 bytes
[INFO] Merger - Merging 2 sorted segments
```

Comment: How much heap do the tasks have? They have to spill to disk very frequently with 44736 bytes and then merge it on disk. Basically increase the `-Xmx` setting in `mapred.child.java.opts`.

Comment: How many reducers are you running for this job?